# Should I use rel=index or rel=contents in this instance?

Tags: seo, html

I’m creating an MMA website. There’s the home page, there’s a fighters section whose index page lists fighters in the organisation, and then each fighter has a profile page. The URL structure is like this:

```
/
/fighters/
/fighters/john-doe
```

My question is: on the fighter’s profile page I want to link to the fighters index page (`/fighters`). In my HTML page, which meta tag would be the most appropriate?

```
<link href="/fighters/" rel="index" />
```

Or:

```
<link href="/fighters/" rel="contents" />
```

I’m having trouble distinguishing which would be best, and whether `rel="index"` would be the index for the whole site or the current page/section I’m viewing?

Comment: Those two meta tags have no SEO value as search engines do not recognize them.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no evidence of browsers or search engines doing anything with either of the link types `index` and `contents`. Thus, using them appears to be futile, even though they are mentioned in the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.12), with vague descriptions. Only `index` is mentioned in the [existing rel values](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) document (cited in the HTML5 CR). Neither of these descriptive documents gives a solid definition of what the link types would really mean, and this is part of the reasons for their being ignored.

You should have a normal link (`<a href=...>...</a>`) in the body of the document. This lets both users and search engines access the site index. Normal links are what search engines primarily use; `link` elements are metadata, largely write-only code (i.e., futily written attempts at affecting search engines).